# Realloc function returning a null pointer when manipulating strings

Tags: c, realloc

i've been trying some stuff with the realloc function and ran into a problem with strings:

```
char *s="hello";

s=realloc(s,size); // this return null

char *p;
p=malloc(5);

strcpy(p,"hello");

p=realloc(p,size) // this works fine
```

why does the first declaration fail?

Comment: You cannot `realloc` a string literal. The pointer needs to either be a null-pointer or point to memory allocated by another suitable allocation function (e.g.: `malloc`)

Comment: @Rafik Bouloudene You can reallocate only what was allocated with malloc, calloc and realloc.

Comment: You may only pass a pointer to `realloc` that was returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` ealier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line declares `s` and reserves some static storage space for `"hello"`, then assigns a pointer to it to `s`.

```
char *s="hello";
```

This second line is trying to `realloc` memory that was never dynamically allocated. In fact, it's static.

```
s=realloc(s,size); // this return null
```

No wonder it fails. Actually, it could very well crash your program, it's undefined behavior! You can only use `realloc` or `free` on memory that was previously returned by a call to `malloc` (or variants). Nothing else.

See also:

- [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go)
- [C: do all string literals have static storage duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667780/c-do-all-string-literals-have-static-storage-duration)